# Is there a way to put a gradient colored border around a container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, border

What I have:

```dart
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration( 
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
          border: Border.all(
            color: const Color(0xFFE800E8),//<---- Insert Gradient Here 
            width: 1.5,
          )
        ),
),
```

[image]

This a visual representation of the border, which is currently pink, this is what I want to make gradient:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a simpler way. But you could construct it using a couple of containers like this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Colors.black,
        Colors.pinkAccent,
      ],
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
  ),
  height: 100,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.5),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Enter further widgets here'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image: Gradient border]

Answer (score 0):

We can implement it by creating our own BoxBorder. I am adding a snippet below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientBoxBorder extends BoxBorder {
  final Gradient gradient;
  final double width;

  const GradientBoxBorder({
    required this.gradient,
    this.width = 1.0,
  });

  @override
  BorderSide get bottom => BorderSide.none;

  @override
  BorderSide get top => BorderSide.none;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(width);

  @override
  bool get isUniform => true;

  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    BoxShape shape = BoxShape.rectangle,
    BorderRadius? borderRadius,
  }) {
    if (shape == BoxShape.rectangle) {
      if (borderRadius != null) {
        _paintRRect(canvas, rect, borderRadius);
      } else {
        _paintRect(canvas, rect);
      }
    } else {
      _paintCircle(canvas, rect);
    }
  }

  void _paintRect(Canvas canvas, Rect rect) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(rect)
      ..strokeWidth = width
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
  }

  void _paintRRect(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, BorderRadius borderRadius) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(rect)
      ..strokeWidth = width
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    final rrect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      rect,
      topLeft: borderRadius.topLeft,
      topRight: borderRadius.topRight,
      bottomLeft: borderRadius.bottomLeft,
      bottomRight: borderRadius.bottomRight,
    );
    canvas.drawRRect(rrect, paint);
  }

  void _paintCircle(Canvas canvas, Rect rect) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(rect)
      ..strokeWidth = width
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawCircle(rect.center, rect.shortestSide / 2, paint);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Use it like:

```
         Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: GradientBoxBorder(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [
                    AppColors.primary[900]!,
                    AppColors.primary[500]!,
                  ],
                ),
                width: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```